# how to do to join the adress mail with "mailto", in javascript?

Tags: html, api, google-apps-script

Using google app script, the adresse mail filled in the variable , from google sheet API and then, I want to join "mailto:" with the variable of adress mail . This allows to appear this variable in html .
How to do it ?

**in google app script:**

```
var Email_user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
          var hrefmail = "mailto:"+Email_user ;
          var val_htm_mail_1 =hrefmail ; 
:
:
:
 theHTML.linkEmail = val_htm_mail_1; ( this is to fill the variable "val_htm_mail_1" to send it to HTML
```

**in html :**

```
 <span id="linkEmail"><?=linkEmail?></span><br />
```

thank you in advance for this helpness

Comment: So are you unable to get the email address from the Google sheet?

Comment: Have you tried to use console.log() or Logger.log() to check the value of hrefmail?

Comment: Thank you for yours answers. Of course, I tested using console.log() or Logger.log(). It works all but, it doesn't work for the displayed  blue adresse mail where I click to display the little window as a mail to write there  and then, directly send it ...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using HTML DOM Edit HTML content instead of a scriptlet. Here's the [w3 reference](http://www.w3big.com/htmldom/htmldom-content.html) so you can try to write it yourself, instead of just copying mine. Here is an example program:

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate();
}
function include(filename) {
  var Email_user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var hrefmail = "mailto:"+Email_user ;
  val_htm_mail_1 = hrefmail ;
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="linkEmail">...</span><br/>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("linkEmail").innerHTML = this.val_htm_mail_1;
    </script>
    <?!= include ('javascript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript.html

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

*Note you may need to adjust this depending on your browser settings

Comment: thank you for your answer. I found an other method, thanks of the assistant google API. Here is my method :